# How can I cast a gcroot<Object^> to IMyInterface in C++.net?

Tags: .net, casting, c++-cli, visual-c++

I'm having to do some weird things with gcroot, but I get the following error on the dynamic cast line:  "cannot use 'dynamic_cast' to convert from 'gcroot' to 'IMyInterface^'.  In C#, you could easily cast a generic object to any interface.  You may get a runtime error if the object doesn't implement the interface but it would compile.

```
gcroot<Object^> m_pDataObject;
IMyInterface obj = dynamic_cast<IMyInterface^>(m_pDataObject);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works (compiles) and should do what you want (module replacing `IDisposable` with your required interface):

```
gcroot<Object^> m_pDataObject;
Object^ obj = m_pDataObject;     // implicit conversion from gcroot<>
IDisposable^ intf = dynamic_cast<IDisposable^>(obj);    // or safe_cast<>
```

Answer (score 7):

gcroot<> is a smart pointer.  You can cast to get the tracking handle out of it:

```
IMyInterface^ itf = dynamic_cast<IMyInterface^>((Object^)m_pDataObject);
```

Steve's answer is fine too btw.